# Iptables rules depending on network connected to

Tags: networking, iptables

I've struggling around something I would like to put in place. 
I use my ubuntu 18.04 laptop at work and at home.

I would like my iptables to drop all incoming connections (except established ones of course) when I'm not home, but it would allow access to port 22 for instance when I'm at home.

I'm really not sure how to handle this issue, since I don't know how to identify the fact that I'm at home directly in an iptables rule. I thought about trying to have a script run when a network is connected, ping a distant server to get my public ip address and then to flush iptables / set new rules. I don't like this solution because it is not clean and that I may have some ports opened for a few seconds (just after the connection / before receiving the external ip address), which is something I don't like

Do you have any idea about how I can handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could identify "being home" by your network address and do:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Where you exchange the 192.168.0.0/24 with the address of your local network at home.
This will still open the port when you are in a network with the same network address and subnet as your home network though so you should choose one that's not very common.

But this was just to answer your question on how to identify "home". This is neither a proper nor a safe method you should rely on to secure an SSH server (think of IP-Spoofing). Better follow proven security guidelines, e.g. 2FA, changing common ports, using key authentication, disable root logins, blocking failed attempts etc.

See this: 
https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/04/10-steps-to-secure-open-ssh

Comment: The approach you suggest would work much better with IPv6. It's still not completely foolproof, but if combined with proper securing of the ssh server, it would be quite sensible. Identifying localhost traffic by the IP address is probably not the best way to do it. I'd instead have started with a rule saying `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, it's a bad way to do it and absolutely not safe, I just answered the question and then gave my 2 cents on what would be better. Thanks for the downvote though.